# Usando localStorage para ocultar un div

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Básicamente el problema que tengo es que no sé cómo ocultar el `input` y el botón con `localstorage`, así cuando refresque la página no me muestre el `input` ni el botón, sólo el nombre.

HTML

```html
<span id="label-user"></span><br>
<input type="text" id="inpuname" />
<input type="button" onclick="saveLogin()" value="Save" id="save"/>
```

JavaScript

```js
function saveLogin(){
  var labelUser = localStorage.getItem("usuarioname");
  $("#label-user").text(labelUser);
  localStorage.setItem( "usuarioname", document.getElementById("inpuname").value );
  document.getElementById("label-user").innerHTML += document.getElementById("inpuname").value;
};
saveLogin()

jQuery(function(){
         jQuery('#save').click(function(){
               jQuery('#inpuname').hide();
               jQuery('#save').hide();
    });
});
```

Código
https://jsfiddle.net/JDLA1/zfgjr41s/18/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He separado la funcion `saveLogin()` en dos. Dejando `saveLogin` para lo que es el guardado del input en el `localStorage` y la funcion, `cargarLabel` que rellena el label con el valor.

Asi cuando carga la pagina, llamas solo a `cargarLabel`. Si existe valor, se rellena y se ocultan el input y el boton. Si no hay valor que meter, se hace el proceso normal.

No haria falta la funcion jQuery que tenias porque ahora al hacer save, se llama a `saveLogin` que llama a `cargarLabel` y oculta los componentes.

```js
function saveLogin() {

  localStorage.setItem("usuarioname", document.getElementById("inpuname").value);
  cargarLabel();
};
cargarLabel();

function cargarLabel() {
  var labelUser = localStorage.getItem("usuarioname");
  if (labelUser) {

    //alert("ocultando");
    jQuery('#inpuname').hide();
    jQuery('#save').hide();
    $("#label-user").text(labelUser);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<span id="label-user"></span>
<br>
<input type="text" id="inpuname" />
<input type="button" onclick="saveLogin()" value="Save" id="save" />
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/zfgjr41s/21/

Comment: Cool! ya lo habia echo con cookies! pero este esta bueno, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Quizá con una condición que compruebe si tienes nombre en localStorage?

```
...
var labelUser = localStorage.getItem("usuarioname")
if (labelUser) {
  jQuery('#inpuname').hide()
  jQuery('#save').hide()
}
...
```

Comment: lo mismo que se me ocurrió, pero te he *ninja'deado* xDD +1